# Change dropzone thumbnail with cropped canvas image canvas null error

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, crop, dropzone.js

I want to crop image with canvas and to change dropzone thumbnail after success I'm using this code:

```
success: function (file,responseText) {
            $('#dzImageHidden').val(responseText);
            if (responseText) {
                var imageUrl ='{{ asset('uploads/dz/') }}' + '/' + responseText;
                var img = $('<img id="target">'); 
                img.attr('src', imageUrl);


                var image = new Image(); 
                var canvas = document.getElementById('img');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                image.src = imageUrl; 

                file.previewElement.querySelector("[data-dz-thumbnail]").src = ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 165);
            }
```

I got this error :

> TypeError: canvas is null

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is null because of this: `var canvas = document.getElementById('img');`

You have selected the tag img, not an id.